# Editing HTML with Beautiful Soup has led to black diamond question marks instead of spaces

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, utf

I am using beautiful soup to add buttons to the html that is produced when I use python's difflib library. This works *almost* perfectly - the only issue is that all spaces in my output are now black diamond question marks.

Vaguely, my function looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def addbuttons():
    global differencehtml
    soup = BeautifulSoup(differencehtml, 'html.parser')

    # edit soup here

    differencehtml = soup.prettify()
```

When I open the output file in chrome, all the spaces have been replaced by the  black question marks. I don't think it has to do with the edits I'm doing, because if I comment out addbuttons() and have this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(differencehtml, 'html.parser')
differencehtml = soup.prettify()
```

I still end up with the black diamond question marks instead of spaces:
[like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IVzS.png)

What is it about prettify() that is affecting the spaces? How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you getting `differencehtml` ?  Can you show the code for this?

Comment: Sure: differencehtml = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(fromlines=file1_lines, 
                                           tolines=file2_lines,
                                           fromdesc="old: ",
                                           todesc="new: ")

Comment: (sorry about the formatting).

Comment: When I print differencehtml, it shows up as: ▒  which is \u2592. I've tried differencehtml = differencehtml.replace(▒, " "), but this results in the error " invalid character in identifier" because it doesn't recognize the block element

Comment: As an update - I don't think the issue is happening in prettify(), it's happening in 
soup = BeautifulSoup(differencehtml, 'html.parser') because when I print soup immediately afterwards, it has the weird symbols

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question, it is better than trying to add code into a comment.

Comment: The issue could actually be with how the HTML file was saved or is loaded. You probably need to add an `encoding='utf-8'` parameter to your `open()` (if you are using Python 3.x)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!